# Redirecting subdomain to folder in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I need to redirect help.mydomain.com/a-page to /pages/a-page without using Nginx or Apache redirects and only through Rails 3 routes.

The key here is the help subdomain determining that /pages/ should be dropped from the route although the view is under the /views/pages/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does the bounty work? I am pretty sure I answered you question correctly. Let me know if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
match "/:page_name" => redirect("/pages/%{page_name}"), :constraints => { :subdomain => /help/ }
```

Comment: You may want the constraint to be more specific. Especially if you have multiple subdomains doing this.

Comment: Hi @twmills, do you know also how to redirect any subdomain.example.com/bla-bla TO example.com/subdomain/bla-bla ?