# url_for rewrite on Rails -> add extra prefix (folder) at beginning of every URL on specific request.host

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like rewrite url_for method in a way it prepends /extra_dir/ to every URL.

```
module UrlHelper
  def url_for(options = nil)
    if request.host.include? "special_subdomain."
       "/extra_dir" + super(options)) 
    else
       super(options)
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is because url_for is called more than once for each URL. E.g. For every *_path call and for every link_to. That causes that link's URLs are like: /extra_dir/extra_dir/....

I can check if "extra_dir" is already at beggining of URL but I have a feeling that there is better way to do it ..

**I can not use namespace/scope since there is also "host" rule. Something like "conditional" scope based on host might be a solution.**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can add all routs(which you want to prefix with "/extra_dir") in a scope as follow

```
scope "extra_dir" do
  #### your routes
end
```

**Suggestion**

Normally I would configure the webserver to do these kind of redirects.

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088174/redirecting-subdomain-to-folder-in-rails-3). It might help you.

Comment: I'd use this - no messing with Rails core then

Comment: I can not use namespace/scope since this rule is in fact more complex - it should happen only on specific host  :( (special_subdomain.domain.tdl). Something like "conditional" scope based on hose might be a solution.